# Unchecked call to 'continueWithTask....' as a member of raw type

Tags: java, android, firebase

I get this warning on all three methods, I tried to search stackoverflow for a solution but could not figure it out how the available solution would apply in my case. Even though the code works fine as expected but the code block gets highlighted in yellow and seems to constantly ask for attention. Thank you for your help!

```
        final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(mStorageRef).child(mFileName);
        final StorageTask storageTask = storageReference.putFile(intentDataUri);

        storageTask.addOnProgressListener((OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>) taskSnapshot -> {
            double p = 100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            progressDialog.setMessage((int) p + getString(R.string.percent_of) + taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount() +getString(R.string.strUploading));
        }).continueWithTask((Continuation) task -> {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                throw task.getException();
            }
            return storageReference.getDownloadUrl();
        }).addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<Uri>) uriTask -> {
```

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, do you think you could help here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the issue, I modified the code as below and it no longer throws that warning, replaced StorageTask with UploadTask and it worked -

```
        final String messageID = databaseReference.child(getResources().getString(R.string.dbrefMessage)).child(mCurrentUserID)
                .child(mMsgReceiverID).push().getKey();
        final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(mStorageRef).child(mFileName);
        final UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(uri);

        uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(taskSnapshot -> {
            double p = 100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            progressDialog.setMessage((int) p + getString(R.string.percent_of) + taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount() + getString(R.string.strUploading));
        }).continueWithTask(task -> {
            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                throw task.getException();
            }
            return storageReference.getDownloadUrl();
        }).addOnCompleteListener(uriTask -> {
```